# Navigation portlet: all childen always expanded

Tags: navigation, portlet, plone

How can I make the navigation portlet show children even for unselected folders? I mean initial tree state is fully expanded (at least for one level, ie: direct children).

I'm looking at INavtreeStrategy, SitemapNavtreeStrategy and INavigationQueryBuilder but no insights so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it looking at Products/CMFPlone/browser/sitemap.py

I just had to use its query builder instead. Here's the code:

```
from Acquisition import aq_inner
from zope.component import getMultiAdapter

from plone.memoize.instance import memoize

from plone.app.layout.navigation.interfaces import INavtreeStrategy
from plone.app.layout.navigation.navtree import buildFolderTree

from plone.app.portlets.portlets import navigation
from Products.CMFPlone.browser.navtree import SitemapQueryBuilder


class Renderer(navigation.Renderer):

    @memoize
    def getNavTree(self, _marker=[]):
        context = aq_inner(self.context)
        **queryBuilder = SitemapQueryBuilder(context)**
        strategy = getMultiAdapter((context, self.data), INavtreeStrategy)

        return buildFolderTree(context, obj=context, query=queryBuilder(), strategy=strategy)
```

Then I registered a portlet renderer with:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
    xmlns:plone="http://namespaces.plone.org/plone">

  <include package="plone.app.portlets" />


  <plone:portletRenderer
      portlet="plone.app.portlets.portlets.navigation.INavigationPortlet"
      layer="..browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific"
      class=".navigation.Renderer"
      />

</configure>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation of ExtendedPathIndex

http://plone.org/products/extendedpathindex

A combination of navtree and depth parameter should give you what you need.