# Is there a way to do a portal_catalog that keeps the hierarchical structure?

Tags: plone, plone-3.x

Suppose:

```
Folder
  - Document
  - Document
  - Folder1
    - Document
    - Document
```

If I do a portal_catalog using Folder as path, I get:

```
[<Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at 0xdba8d9c>, 

<Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at 0xdd71234>, 

<Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at 0xdd71324>, 

<Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at 0xdd712fc>, 

<Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at 0xdd71194>]
```

But I would like to have a portal_catalog that keeps the *hierarchical* context, like:

```
{
    "Folder": 
             [
             <Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at 0xdba8d9c>,
<Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at 0xdba8d9c>, 
              {
               "Folder1":[
                          <Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at 0xdba8d9c>, <Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at 0xdba8d9c>
                         ]
              }
             ]
}
```

So, if it's a folderish type, it's id is a key from a dict.

Is is possible to have a similar data strcuture (that keeps the object's hierarchical structure), or will I have to create my own recursive function (I know the structure above will possibly don't exist, but I think you can get the idea)? I'm thinking about using `portal_catalog` and brains because of performace issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, you should be careful with this.  It's likely you're trying to solve the wrong problem or trying to solve a good problem the wrong way.  Feel free to say more about why you're doing this and there may be better answers.

Comment: I'm replicating an object structure from a context to another context, but only with some content-types. The second context will not have the same type of objects, it'll have others but with the same id and title.

Comment: But why are you trying to do this?  This needs a lot more context.

Comment: I cant give more details... :( The fact is, the first context will have a lot of content types that Im interested in ther id/name, that will be used in another context, that will have local permissions, but need to have the same structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can `sort_on` the `path` index.  That means your catalog query results will be sorted by hierarchy.  Then you can use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in a recursive manner to get an iterator over the structure you describe.  The tricky part will be the recursion.  You'll want to use a key func for groupby that selects the appropriate portion of brain.getPath() for the current folder depth/level of recursion.

Comment: I am afraid you cannot sort on ExtendedPathIndex. You'd have to do the sort manually or use a separate sortable_path index that's a FieldIndex.

Comment: Hmm, I know I did this once, but maybe that was before ExtendedPathIndex was the default.

Comment: I had to deal with this exact same usecase not so long ago, using ExtendedPathIndex..

Comment: The sortable_path is a good approach. I can iter through the list I received from portal_catalog, and do the processing I need from that sequential list instead of creating an intermediary structure with dicts like above. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might also have a look at the sitemap generator, which delivers a nested navigation structure.

Here, a (bit) related link: [Navigation portlet: all childen always expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312007/navigation-portlet-all-childen-always-expanded)